# Gnome, show authentication dialog

Tags: linux, authentication, root, privileges, sudo

I am writing a GUI application using Qt. I am  I want to use super-user/root privileges to run a terminal command inside my GUI application. My application is not started as super-user/root.

Using gksu on Ubuntu and kdesu on KDE-based distributions, solve the problem. But other Gnome-based distributions doesn't have a GUI utility to provide authentication dialog for the su or sudo terminal commands.

Installing beesu is an option but I want to use stock installed authentication utilities such as gksu or kdesu. In Fedora 17 Gnome for example, there is an authentication dialog that is displayed when the user wants to install some software using the Add/Remove Software tool. Here is the dialog:
http://dox.abv.bg/files/fdw?eid=87844171

This authentication dialog is probably integrated in Fedora's Add/Remove Software utility, since when it shows up no additional processes are launched as it becomes obvious from the System Monitor tool.

Here is a greater explanation on the case:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18737/

I have the same problem using openSuse 12.1 Gnome linux.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a window in Qt and pass the input to sudo / su?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of creating it myself. The only thing I should take care about is when the password is wrong.

Comment: You can use some variant of expect to capture the standard out to see if it was successful or not.